# PineScript calculate EMA for One Candle in Future in Tradingview

Tags: plot, series, pine-script

I want to calculate an exponential-moving-average (EMA) with the EMA for one Candle in the future just by duplicating the last candle.

Means I want to plot an EMA with an offset of 1 and the value, that is in the offset 1 bar is calculated based on the current candle.

Unfortunately I think I have a wrong understanding of the series, why it doesn't work.
But hopefully my code shows what I wanted to do:

```
CustomEma(source, length) =>
alpha = 2 / (length + 1)
ema = 0.0
// iterate through the length e.g. calculate with a length of 20
for i = 1 to length
    y=length-i
    //now calculate the ema for bar 21,20,19 until 1 based on source from 20 to 0
    ema[y+1] = alpha * source[y] + (1 - alpha) * nz(ema[y+1])
//now calculate the last EMA by duplicating the source 0
ema[0]= alpha * source[0] + (1 - alpha) * nz(ema[1])
ema

esaF = CustomEma(close, 20)
plot(esaF , color=color.white,offset=1)
```

Hope a lot on your help.

Thanks in advance

Maybe the following Picture shows what I want to do:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05HOM.png)

Comment: See the definition of [ema](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_ema). It shows an example on how to calculate it. I'm not following your calculation logic though. You're calculating with a length of 20, but in reality you're including 21 datapoints. The length is part of alpha, so your calculation could be wrong, no?

Comment: Yes thank you. I know, the code ist just schematic, not working. I added a picture with the target I want to achieve.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, when you enter a length of 20 in your function `CustomEma(source, length)` you want to calculate the ema over a length of 21 bars? The 21st bar being a duplicate of the last bar?

Comment: Should be about 20 bars, but based on a series where the last candle is a duplicate of the "real" last bar (that is the current bar)...

Comment: There's no "about" in coding. This is an exact science. So, to recap, when you enter a length of 20, you want to calculate the ema of 20 elements, of which the first 19 elements are the 19 most recent bars, and the 20th element should be a duplicate of the last bar. Correct?

Comment: Yes :-)
Thats exacly what I want, but where I have the issue with the "duplication".

Answer (score 2):

See [How Is the Exponential Moving Average (EMA) Formula Calculated?](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/122314/what-exponential-moving-average-ema-formula-and-how-ema-calculated.asp) for the formula used.
It's based on yesterday's `ema`, and uses the current price to calculate today's `ema`.
When we consider the latest bar's `ema` as yesterday's `ema`, then we simply have to use the latest bar's price as today's price to calculate the new `ema`.

```
//@version=4
study("Custom EMA", "cema", overlay=true)

// Source: https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/122314/what-exponential-moving-average-ema-formula-and-how-ema-calculated.asp
// EMA = Price(t)×k + EMA(y)×(1−k)
// where:
// t = today
// y = yesterday
// N = number of days in EMA
// k = 2÷(N+1)
//
// In our case, the 'yesterday' ema is the current ema for the latest candle.
// The 'today' ema is calculated using that 'yesterday' ema as 'previous' ema.
// For the 'today' price we take the latest candle (which is essentially a 'copy' of the last bar).
// When we plug that into the formula, we get the new ema.

custom_ema(src, length) =>
    k = 2 / (length + 1)
    new_ema = (src * k) + (ema(src, length) * (1 - k))
    
esaF = custom_ema(close, 20)
plot(esaF , color=color.white,offset=1)
```

Edit: Code update to show custom ema only on last bar

```
//@version=4
study("Custom EMA", "cema", overlay=true)

// Source: https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/122314/what-exponential-moving-average-ema-formula-and-how-ema-calculated.asp
// EMA = Price(t)×k + EMA(y)×(1−k)
// where:
// t = today
// y = yesterday
// N = number of days in EMA
// k = 2÷(N+1)
//
// In our case, the 'yesterday' ema is the current ema for the latest candle.
// The 'today' ema is calculated using that 'yesterday' ema as 'previous' ema.
// For the 'today' price we take the latest candle (which is essentially a 'copy' of the last bar).
// When we plug that into the formula, we get the new ema.

var float cema = na
var float rema = na
var float mema = na


custom_ema(src, length) =>
    k = 2 / (length + 1)
    new_ema = (src * k) + (ema(src, length) * (1 - k))

real_ema(src, length) => ema(src, length)

mixed_ema(src, length) =>
    if barstate.isconfirmed
        rema
    else
        cema

cema := custom_ema(close, 20)
rema := real_ema(close, 20)
mema := mixed_ema(close, 20)
    
plot(cema, "custom ema", color=color.white)
plot(rema, "real ema",   color=color.green)
plot(mema, "mixed ema",  color=color.red)
```

Comment: Hi Björn,

that looks like a great answer :-)

Thank you so much.

Just thinking two thinks:

Shouldn't be the ema(src, length) --> ema(src,(length-1)), as one value comes with the first part?

And second, I was asking myself how to now add two ema values in the future?

new_ema = (src * k) + (ema(src, length-1) * (1 - k))
new_ema2 = (src * k) + (new_ema(src, length-1) * (1 - k))


Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Additionally just dropped the code into Tradinview and tested if the standard ema is similar to the custom ema until the last candle (without future) and it seems as there is a minor bug in the code as the lines are not 100% above each other?
custom_ema(src, length) =>
    k = 2 / (length + 1)
    new_ema =(src * k) + (ema(src, length) * (1 - k))
esa = ema(close, 20)
esa2 = custom_ema(close, 20)
plot(esa2, color=color.white,offset=1,linewidth=6)
plot(esa, color=color.green, linewidth=5)

Comment: The `custom_ema()` function will never be identical to the native `ema()` function, because for every bar, you're including that same bar as the 'extra' element in the calculation. If it's your intention to only do that 'extra' calculation on the final bar on the chart, that cannot be done. Why? Because Pine runs your script on every single bar. Ask yourself this: Suppose the 'extra' it's only calculated on the final bar, what happens when the next bar comes along? You can't update that calculation on the previous bar anymore, which you now want to be the native `ema`.

Comment: About my previous comment. I found a way to actually only show the `new_ema` on the last bar. Updated my answer to include the code example.

Comment: Great thanks.

But I'm asking myself why in 
new_ema = (src * k) + (ema(src, length) * (1 - k)) every bars ema is changing and not only the last one.

Following function is 1:1 the "real" ema also in tradingview. I'm just asking if it is there not possible to just add the last ema based on the latest candl. Like in an array to move everything one to left recalculate only the last value.

CustomEma(source, length) =>
    alpha = 2 / (length + 1)
    baseema = 0.0
    baseema := alpha * source + (1 - alpha) * nz(baseema[1])

Comment: That would mean that the 'future' value you're looking for is actually just the latest ema. So you already know what it is. No need for calculating that.

Comment: Ahh great, I think I got it know :D Needed some more time to think about :-)
One last question, when I know want to predict more than one EMA in the future e.g. two, would that work that way:

custom_ema(src, length) =>
    k = 2 / (length + 1)
    new_ema = (src * k) + (ema(src, length) * (1 - k))
    new_ema = (src * k) + (new_ema  * (1 - k))

Comment: Correct. But written like that won't compile. You'll have to declare a `var` inside the function to hold the `new_ema` and use `:=` to assign a value to it. Something like this: `custom_ema(src, length) => var float new_ema = na      k = 2 / (length + 1)      new_ema := (src * k) + (ema(src, length) * (1 - k))      new_ema := (src * k) + (new_ema * (1 - k))`

Comment: This is so cool :-)
Thank you  veeeerrryyy much.


Now I'm coming to a next question, because I'm mixing the emas a bit like:
forecastEmaX = ema(abs(sourcePlusTwoCandle(source, length)- cema), length)


Question is, is there also a way to get the SOURCE modified. 
Idea was, but I don't get this compiled... :(

sourcePlusTwoCandle(src , length) =>
   if not barstate.isconfirmed
   newSource = 0.0
   for i = 2 to length+2
      newSource[i]=src [i-2]
   newSource[1]=src [0]
   newSource[0]=src [0]

Comment: Could you put that into a new question please, with code example included? You can put a link in it to this question for clarity. I'm asking because it's a policy of stackoverflow that questions should only pertain to a single problem. If not, this question might be deleted, or moved to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) by the moderators. If you feel this answer solved you initial question, you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank you very much. Of coure I've opened a new thread for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968694/pinescript-create-a-source-with-n-candles-in-future-for-forcasts-in-tradingview